# Keep variables type after using data frame

Tags: dataframe, julia, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to use `kproto()`  function  from R package `clustMixType` to cluster mixed-type data in Julia, but I'm getting error `No numeric variables in x! Try using kmodes() from package...`. My data should have 3 variables: 2 continuous and 1 categorical. It seems after I used `DataFrame()` all the variables became categorical. Is there a way to avoid changing  the variables type  after using `DataFrame()` so that I have mixed-type data (continuous and categorical) to use `kproto()`?

```
using RCall
@rlibrary clustMixType

# group 1 variables
x1=rand(Normal(0,3),10)
x2=rand(Normal(1,2),10)
x3=["1","1","2","2","0","1","1","2","2","0"]
g1=hcat(x1,x2,x3) 

# group 2 variables
y1=rand(Normal(0,4),10)
y2=rand(Normal(-1,6),10)
y3=["1","1","2","1","1","2","2","0","2","0"]
g2=hcat(y1,y2,y3)
 
#create the data
df0=vcat(g1,g2)
df1 = DataFrame(df0) 

#use R function
R"kproto($df1, 2)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about the R package and what kind of input it expects, but the issue is probably how you construct the data matrix from which you construct your DataFrame, not the DataFrame constructor itself.

When you concatenate a numerical and a string column, Julia falls back on the element type `Any` for the resulting matrix:

```
julia> g1=hcat(x1,x2,x3)
10×3 Matrix{Any}:
  0.708309  -4.84767   "1"
  0.566883  -0.214217  "1"
...
```

That means your `df0` matrix is:

```
julia> #create the data
       df0=vcat(g1,g2)
20×3 Matrix{Any}:
  0.708309   -4.84767   "1"
  0.566883   -0.214217  "1"
...
```

and the `DataFrame` constructor will just carry this lack of type information through rather than trying to infer column types.

```
julia> DataFrame(df0)
20×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1         x2         x3  
     │ Any        Any        Any 
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.708309   -4.84767   1
   2 │ 0.566883   -0.214217  1
...
```

A simple way of getting around this is to just not concatenate your columns into a single matrix, but to construct the DataFrame from the columns:

```
julia> DataFrame([vcat(x1, y1), vcat(x2, y2), vcat(x3, y3)])
20×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1         x2          x3     
     │ Float64    Float64     String 
─────┼───────────────────────────────
   1 │  0.708309   -4.84767   1
   2 │  0.566883   -0.214217  1
...
```

As you can see, we now have two `Float64` numerical columns `x1` and `x2` in the resulting DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the nice answer by Nils (as the problem is indeed when a matrix is constructed not when `DataFrame` is created) there is this little trick:

```
julia> df = DataFrame([1 1.0 "1"; 2 2.0 "2"], [:int, :float, :string])
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ int  float  string
     │ Any  Any    Any
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ 1    1.0    1
   2 │ 2    2.0    2

julia> identity.(df)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ int    float    string
     │ Int64  Float64  String
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │     1      1.0  1
   2 │     2      2.0  2
```